# What do you call someone that grew up in a poor background but has became very rich?

Tags: single-word-requests

The question is self-explanatory. A person that rose up from the american poverty line to become rich and famous.

Answer (score 2):

A ***[self-made man:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+Self-Made+Man)***

> One who became successful and/or wealthy through hard work and not by inheritance or help from others.

Comment: This exactly answered my question